# Plucking classical and acoustic guitars

Tags: fingerstyle-guitar

I have played the classical guitar for a few years but have recently started giving acoustic guitar a go. I have obviously noticed a few differences but there is one thing I am not sure about. When you pluck the notes with your right hand (I am right handed) do you have you hand in a different sort of shape than classical guitar. For example, I know with classical guitar your right hand looks like this:

[image]

However, in acoustic guitar is it different?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can play an acoustic guitar exactly the same way.  It can be more difficult since there is generally less space between the strings, but is still doable especially if you keep your nails in good shape (which may be difficult since steel or copper strings will put more wear on them than nylon does).

There are many different ways to play that are all perfectly valid, however.  Try different things and see what works best for you.